# Comparing the Least Common Multiple to a Binomial Coefficient

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality, binomial-coefficients, factorial, least-common-multiple

Let $l_{an,n}$ be the [least common multiple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple) for $an+1, an+2, \dots, an+n$

I have found that for all $a$ and $n$ (details can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2203236/48606)):

$$\frac{(an+n)!}{(an!)l_{an,n}} \le (n-1)!$$

This suggests to me that the following is true:

$$\frac{l_{an,n}}{n} \ge {{an+n}\choose{n}}$$

Here is my argument:

(1)  $l_{an,n}[(n-1)!] \ge \dfrac{(an+n)!}{an!}$

(2)  $\dfrac{l_{an,n}[(n-1)!]}{n!} \ge {{an+n}\choose{n}}$

(3)  $\dfrac{l_{an,n}}{n} \ge {{an+n}\choose{n}}$