# Hands-on argument for base p version of Legendre's formula

Tags: elementary-number-theory, valuation-theory

A formula that I never memorized by heart is $v_p(n!) = \frac{n-s}{p-1}$ where $s$ is the sum of the digits of $n$ in base $p$.

While it follows in a few lines from Legendre's formula, the reason I didn't memorize the above is that I do not yet grasp it intuitively. Is there a "hands-on" argument from which one "immediately" sees that this fraction has to be the correct term (other than the straightforward computation from Legendre's formula)?

Comment: Is the Wikipedia article's [proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_formula#Proof_2) for this what you mean by "in a few lines from Legendre's formula"? I just want to make sure that if I try answering this, then I know what specifically I am to compare my solution with to confirm I am actually addressing your stated concerns.

Comment: @JohnOmielan Yes, it is.

Comment: We have $v_p(n!)  - v_p((n-1)!) = v_p(n)$, and rearranging $s_p(n) - s_p(n-1) = 1 - (p-1)\cdot v_p(n)$ gives $$v_p(n) = \frac{1 - s_p(n) + s_p(n-1)}{p-1} = \frac{\bigl(n - s_p(n)\bigr) - \bigl((n-1) - s_p(n-1)\bigr)}{p-1}\,.$$

Comment: @DanielFischer Your suggestion is simpler than mine. As such, since I assumed you won't be adding an answer yourself, I took the liberty of adding a community wiki answer expanding on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Daniel Fischer](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/83702/daniel-fischer)'s question [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3534498/hands-on-argument-for-base-p-version-of-legendres-formula/3802357#comment7837254_3534498) outlines, consider the sum of digits in base $b$ of $i - 1$ compared to $i$. The smallest power (i.e., right-most) non-zero digit of $i$ is decreased by $1$ and all of the $0$ terms, if any, to the right of it are changed to $b - 1$. For example, in base $10$, you get $2100 - 1 = 2099$. Since the number of $0$ terms to the right of the lowest power non-zero one is $\nu_{b}(i)$, this means there's a net change in the digits sum of $-1 + (b - 1)\nu_{b}(i)$. Having $s_p(j)$ be the sum of digits of $j$ in base $p$, this gives for any $i \gt 0$ that

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
s_p(i - 1) & = s_p(i) - 1 + (p - 1)\nu_{p}(i) \\
(p - 1)\nu_{p}(i) & = - s_p(i) + s_p(i - 1) + 1 \\
\nu_{p}(i) & = \frac{- s_p(i) + s_p(i - 1) + 1}{p - 1} \\
\nu_{p}(i) & = \frac{i - s_p(i) + s_p(i - 1) + 1 - i}{p - 1} \\
\nu_{p}(i) & = \frac{(i - s_p(i)) - ((i - 1) - s_p(i - 1))}{p - 1} \\
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{1}\label{eq1B}$$

Since

$$\nu_p(n!) = \sum_{i = 1}^{n}\nu_p(i) \tag{2}\label{eq2B}$$

then \eqref{eq1B} shows \eqref{eq2B} is summing a [telescoping series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series). Thus, each first positive term cancels with the negative term of the next summation item, so all which is left is the positive term of the largest summation item, i.e., $n - s_p(n)$, and the negative term of the first summation item, i.e., $0$. Thus, \eqref{eq2B} becomes

$$\nu_p(n!) = \frac{n - s_p(n)}{p - 1} \tag{3}\label{eq3B}$$

Comment: Very nice :-) There is a little error/typo (or maybe just ambiguous language): Not the smallest non-zero digit is changed but rather the right-most non-zero digit. E.g. $1200 - 1 = 1199$ in base $10$.

Comment: @QiZhu Thanks for pointing out that issue. I had worded it improperly as I meant the lowest power, i.e., right-most, non-zero digit. I've now updated the answer to make this more clear.

Answer (score 2):

With

$$\nu_p(n!) = \frac{n - s}{p - 1} \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

I don't know of any argument allowing you to "immediately" see this is true. Nonetheless, here's a alternate explanation which may not be more "hands-on", but it doesn't directly use the [Legendre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_formula#Proof_2) proof and you may find it more intuitive.

As is done in the linked proof, define

$$n = \sum_{i=0}^{l}n_{i}p^{i} \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

A key element is the net contribution to $\nu_p(n!)$ from each $n_{i}p^{i}$ term in \eqref{eq2A} (as specified by $g(j)$ in \eqref{eq4A} below) is *independent* of all of the other terms' contributions. To see this, first $\forall \; 0 \le j \le l$ define

$$f(j) = \sum_{i=0}^{j}n_{i}p^{i} \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

$$g(j) = \begin{cases}
\emptyset & \text{ if } j = 0, n_0 = 0 \\
[1, f(j)] & \text{ if } j = 0, n_0 \gt 0 \\
[f(j-1) + 1, f(j)] & \text{ if } j \gt 0
\end{cases} \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

For $j \gt 0$, the # of factors of $p$ in the product of the elements of $g(j)$ is given by

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\nu_p\left(\prod_{i=f(j-1)+1}^{f(j)}i\right) & = \sum_{i=f(j-1)+1}^{f(j)}\nu_p(i) \\
& = \sum_{i=1}^{n_jp^j}\nu_p(i) + \sum_{i=n_jp^j + 1}^{f(j)}\nu_p(i) - \sum_{i=1}^{f(j-1)}\nu_p(i) \\
& = \sum_{i=1}^{n_jp^j}\nu_p(i) + \sum_{i=1}^{f(j-1)}\nu_p(n_jp^j + i) - \sum_{i=1}^{f(j-1)}\nu_p(i) \\
& = \sum_{i=1}^{n_jp^j}\nu_p(i) + \sum_{i=1}^{f(j-1)}\left(\nu_p(n_jp^j + i) - \nu_p(i)\right) \\
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{6}\label{eq6A}$$

Note $\nu_p(m)$ is equal to the power of the right-most (i.e., smallest power) non-zero term in the base $p$ expansion of $m$. Since $\forall \; 1 \le i \le f(j-1)$ the right-most non-zero term in the base $p$ expansion of $n_jp^j + i$ and $i$ are the same, you get $\nu_p(n_jp^j + i) - \nu_p(i) = 0$. Thus, the second summation in \eqref{eq6A} is $0$, which means

$$\nu_p\left(\prod_{i=f(j-1)+1}^{f(j)}i\right) = \sum_{i=1}^{n_jp^j}\nu_p(i) \tag{7}\label{eq7A}$$

Among the integers from $1$ to $n_jp^{j}$, there are $n_jp^{j-1}$ with at least one factor of $p$. Among these, there are $n_jp^{j-2}$ integers with at least two factors of $p$. Continue this until you get to there being $n_j$ integers with $j$ factors of $p$. Adding these together gives

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\sum_{i=1}^{n_jp^j}\nu_p(i) & = \sum_{i=0}^{j-1}n_jp^{i} \\
& = n_j\left(\frac{p^{j} - 1}{p - 1}\right) \\
& = \frac{n_jp^{j} - n_j}{p - 1}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{8}\label{eq8A}$$

With $j = 0$, \eqref{eq8A} gives $0$ so it also applies for $g(0)$. Since each set of $g(j)$ in \eqref{eq4A} is disjoint, and the union of them is all the integers up to $n$, then summing \eqref{eq8A} for $0 \le j \le l$ gives the number of factors of $p$ in the product of all integers up to $n$, i.e., $\nu_p(n!)$. Thus,

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\nu_p(n!) & = \sum_{j=0}^{l}\left(\frac{n_jp^{j} - n_j}{p - 1}\right) \\
& = \frac{\sum_{j=0}^{l}n_jp^{j} - \sum_{j=0}^{l}n_j}{p - 1} \\
& = \frac{n - s}{p - 1}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{9}\label{eq9A}$$

Comment: Thank you! Though as far as I can see, this proof is heuristically not much different from the proof linked in Wikipedia. (Also, as in the other post, I think "smallest non-zero term" is ambiguous and "right-most" is better - alternatively, one could simply argue with $\pmod{p^j}$ which is of course exactly the same argument.)

Comment: @QiZhu You're welcome. As with the other answer, I've fixed the wording re: the right-most or lowest power term which is non-zero.